# How to not overlap md-button when window size changes

Tags: angular-material

I am creating three containers .In first container I used md-button,second container I have searchBox and third container I have icons all are working fine. But the button in left container overlapping when window size changes.
Here is my code.

```
<div id="topBarContainer">
  <!--TopBar-->
  <div id="topBarLeft" class="topBar">
    <input type="button" ng-click="newMenuType('message')" value="New" id="newButton">
  </div>
  <!--Top Bar Middle-->
  <div id="topBarMiddle" class="topBar">
    <div class="searchBoxContainer">
      <i class="fa fa-search fa-flip-horizontal" id="searchBoxIcon">&nbsp;</i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Inbox" class="searchBox" ng-model="searchEmail" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Top Bar Right-->
  <div id="topBarRight" class="topBar">
    <div>
      <div class="loginRow">Hi{{loginName()}}</div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!isDeletedView() && emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css.

```
body {
  margin: 0
}
#topBarContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}
#topBarLeft {
  width: 14%;
  text-align: center;
}
#topBarMiddle {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  width: 35%
}
#topBarRight {
  text-align: right;
  background: green;
  flex: 1
}
#topBarRight > div {
  display: inline-flex
}
.topBar {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

How to not to overlap md-button when window is minimizing.

Comment: where is md-button used? I can't see it in your code...can you create a demo? also, the width of md-button is kind of fixed in some aspects, so, you need to make sure your layout is responsive.

Comment: I uswed inside my topBarLeft section. <div id="topBarLeft" class="topBar">
            <md-button class="md-raised" type="button" ng-click="newMenuType('message')" value="New" id="newButton"> New</md-button>
        </div>